# Postgresql: How to find hours between 2 dates and 2 times?

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime, postgresql-9.1

Postgresql 9.1

I'm trying to use a query to find the difference, in fractional/decimal hours, between 2 dates and 2 times for a timesheet system. I'm using the query to make sure the software (not written by me) doesn't have any bugs. Here are the fields in the table I'm using: startdate is a Date field, starttime is a Time field, enddate is a Date field, endtime is a Time field.

I've looked at the [date time docs for 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) and still haven't found what I need.

- age() takes 2 timestamps and appears to give a difference in integer, not fractional, days. I don't think it's possible to multiply the result of age() by 24 to get hours. Nor do I know how to include the time in the age() function.
- I could not find out to convert a date and time to some thing else to use another function.
- I have searched Google and Stackoverflow and have not found info to help me. I've been spending about 4 weeks on this off and on. So probably 30 hours already.
- NOTE: I don't think I can add user-defined functions. I don't have the permissions.

Example data:

- Startdate and time: '2016-04-29' and '23:00:00'
- Enddate and time: '2016-04-30' and '01:30:00'

I've also tried this sql statement.

```
SELECT employeetime.dcmasterid as empid, 
       nonchargeabletime.startdate as ncsdate, 
       nonchargeabletime.starttime as ncstime, 
       nonchargeabletime.enddate as ncedate, 
       nonchargeabletime.endtime as ncetime, 
       employeetime.dchours as normhrs, 
       (timestamp (startdate || ' ' || starttime) - timestamp (enddate || ' ' || endtime)) as diffhrs  
FROM employeetime, nonchargeabletime 
WHERE (nonchargeabletime.employeetime=employeetime.dcautoinc) 
       AND  (nonchargeabletime.startdate >= '2016-04-24') 
       AND (nonchargeabletime.startdate <= '2016-04-30') 
       AND (employeetime.dcmasterid IN ('BLURG')) 
       AND (nonchargeabletime.nonchargeabletype=10) 
ORDER BY employeetime.dcmasterid, nonchargeabletime.startdate, nonchargeabletime.starttime;
```

But I get a syntax error at `startdate` where it says `(timestamp (startdate ||`.

Anyone have any clues how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you not using a single `timestamp` column?

Comment: I didn't design the database. That's what the vendor did. This is mostly a black box system. The fact that I got read access to the db is a minor miracle in itself.

Comment: And : you dont need string concatanation to combine date+time: `(z.startdate+z.starttime)::timestamp` will give you the combined values @a_horse_with_no_name : Ok!

Comment: @wildplasser: you don't even need the cast: `(enddate + endtime) - (startdate + starttime)` will return an `interval`

Comment: @wildplasser: Thanks. My calculated field 'diffhrs' is now returning hours and minutes in this format : `08:50:00`. How do I convert that to decimal hours? Is there a single function to convert that to decimal hours?

Comment: @Bulrush See the horse's anwer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding a `time` to a `date` yields a `timestamp` and subtracting one timestamp from another returns an `interval`.

So all you need to do is:

```
(enddate + endtime) - (startdate + starttime) as diff
```

An `interval` is nice in the context of SQL, but usually harder to handle in a programming language. You can easily convert an `interval` to seconds using `extract(epoch from interval)`

If you want to convert that to hours use `extract` and divide by 3600

```
extract(epoch from (enddate + endtime) - (startdate + starttime))/3600 as diff_hours
```

Comment: That done it! Thank you! But I need to swap the starts with ends otherwise the answer is negative. `extract(epoch from (enddate + endtime) - (startdate + starttime))/3600 as diff_hours.` Oops, I didn't refresh the page in time, you already got that change.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have strings, you can't use || operator, but you can just add time to date (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html).

This should work (you can floor result if you want integer hours):

```
postgres=# create temporary table ts (startdate date, starttime time, enddate date, endtime time);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into ts values('2016-05-03', '11:45:15', '2016-05-04', '13:55:43');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# SELECT startdate,starttime,enddate,endtime, (enddate+endtime)-(startdate+starttime) as interval from ts;
 startdate  | starttime |  enddate   | endtime  |    interval    
------------+-----------+------------+----------+----------------
 2016-05-03 | 11:45:15  | 2016-05-04 | 13:55:43 | 1 day 02:10:28
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT startdate,starttime,enddate,endtime, EXTRACT(epoch FROM ((enddate+endtime)-(startdate+starttime)))/3600 as hours from ts;
 startdate  | starttime |  enddate   | endtime  |      hours       
------------+-----------+------------+----------+------------------
 2016-05-03 | 11:45:15  | 2016-05-04 | 13:55:43 | 26.1744444444444
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH zooi(startdate,starttime, enddate,endtime) AS (
    VALUES('2016-04-29'::date , '23:00:00'::time
        ,'2016-04-30'::date , '01:30:00'::time )
        )
, stamps (sta, sto) AS (
        select (z.startdate+z.starttime)::timestamp
        , (z.enddate+z.endtime)::timestamp
        FROM zooi z
        )
SELECT sta,sto
        , age(sto,sta) AS how_old
        , (sto-sta)::time AS diff
FROM stamps;
```

Next step would be to convert the time (or interval) result to days or hours.